# GVM/Grails shell script bug?

Tags: shell, grails, ubuntu, path, gvm

I'm on Ubuntu (14.04) and just installed the latest version of GVM (1.3.13). I then used it to install Grails (2.3.7), Groovy (2.2.2) and Gradle (1.11).

Groovy and Gradle seem to have installed perfectly fine (I can execute their SDK commands, such as `groovyc`, etc.). But whenever I execute *any* Grails command, from *any* directory, my entire terminal's screen clears, pauses for a second, and then re-draws my command line prompt. The command never gets executed. Several months ago, on Nabble, another user reported [a very similar issue](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-5-on-Ubuntu-td4653913.html).

From the shell, if I execute `echo $GRAILS_HOME`, I get:

> /home/myuser/.gvm/grails/current

If I ececute `echo $PATH` I do see that `/home/myuser/.gvm/grails/current/bin` is on my system path.

So then I decided to dig deeper and actually go to `$GRAILS_HOME`. It's a symbolic link actually pointing to `/home/myuser/.gvm/grails/2.3.7`. So when I go there, I see a normal Grails installation, including a `bin` directory. When I drop into that `bin` dir, I see:

```
grails-debug
grails.bat
grails-debug.bat
startGrails.bat
startGrails
grails
```

I open `grails` (a shell script) and see:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "reset" EXIT
trap "reset" INT
trap "reset" TERM

DIRNAME=`dirname "$0"`
. "$DIRNAME/startGrails"

startGrails org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner "$@"
```

I modified this as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "reset" EXIT
trap "reset" INT
trap "reset" TERM

echo "1..."
sleep 2s

DIRNAME=`dirname "$0"`

echo "2...dirname is $DIRNAME"
sleep 8s

. "$DIRNAME/startGrails"

echo "3..."
sleep 2s

startGrails org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner "$@"
```

And then saved/exited and ran `grails help` from the shell. Here was my output:

```
1...
2...dirname is /home/zharvey/.gvm/grails/current/bin
```

The last line of output ("*2...dirname is...*") pauses for 2 seconds, and then my screen clears (as if I had issued a `clear` command) and my prompt re-appears. At no point in time does my actual command (`grails help`) actually execute or generate output. So it seems that the exact line where the bug exists is:

```
. "$DIRNAME/startGrails"
```

What is this line even doing, and why would it cause the script to fail?

#### My questions

- Can someone confirm that this is in fact a Grails or GVM bug, and not a situation where I have installed something incorrectly?
- **Most importantly**, can someone tell me what I can do to fix this and get Grails up and running as fast as possible?

Comment: Did you _'...open a new terminal, or run the following in the existing one: source "${GVM_DIR}/bin/gvm-init.sh"'_ at the end of installing gvm (as it prints when installation is complete)?

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - no I didn't (originally).  I just did that now, but it didn't change anything. Same functionality as described above still.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and my problem was that I had set the JAVA_HOME variable incorrectly. Although JAVA did work on my machine but was set like :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Clearly, when I looked at it more closely, I found out my mistake and set the above as:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Just a subtle difference, but it did work correctly now and the command

```
grails
```

did not fail silently as explained above.

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out with a bit of (very painful) debugging.

In `GRAILS_HOME/bin/startGrails` (a POSIX script) there is a line that checks to see if `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly.

**I did not install my JDK the recommended way. I don't like using `apt-get` to configure Java for me. I like to download the JDK myself and add `JAVA_HOME` to the `PATH` myself. This was the root of the problem.**

Since `JAVA_HOME` wasn't set up correctly on my Ubuntu machine (because I chose the manual/discouraged approach over the `apt-get` method), the `startGrails` script was failing (silently mind you, c'mon Grails team...) because it couldn't access `JAVA_HOME`:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    die "JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set"
```

So I just changed this to:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    export JAVA_HOME="<value of my $JAVA_HOME var as defined in ~/.bashrc>"
```

I'm going to leave this up since I'm clearly not the only person encountering this.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem. My solution was to `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/startGrails startGrails /opt/grails-2.4.3/bin/startGrails 2`